# Django template doesn't show model items

Tags: python, django

I'm very new to Django and I'm currently trying to create a movie database for a few of my favorite directors. I've been following tutorial videos, and I'm currently trying to get my detail view to display all the added movies for each director. However when I go into the director, it does not display their films.

director/models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Director(models.Model):
    photo = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='none')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    born = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    birth_date = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    married = models.CharField(max_length=1)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Films(models.Model):
    director = models.ForeignKey(Director, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    year = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1, default=0)
    budget = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

director/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

    url(r'^(?P<name_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),

]
```

director/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Director, Films

def index(request):
    all_directors = Director.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'director/index.html', {'all_directors':   all_directors})


def detail(request, name_id):
    try:
        direct = Director.objects.get(pk=name_id)
    except Director.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404("Director not found")
    return render(request, 'director/detail.html', {'direct': direct})
```

director/detail.html

```
<h3 align="center"> {{ direct }} </h3><br>

<img src="{{ director.photo }}">

<h4>Film List</h4>

<ul>
    {% for films in director.films_set.all %}
    <li>{{ direct.title }} - {{ direct.rating }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

When I run the server and go to the page, I click on a director and all it says is the directors name, and "Film List". Please advise on how to fix this, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: In Django, you would normally use the singular `Film` instead of `Films` (just like you have `Director` instead of `Directors`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve it:

```
{% for film in director.films_set.all %}
<li>{{ film.title }} - {{ film.rating }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

You want each movie's title and rating, so I guess using `direct.title` and `direct.rating` was the problem. Also, the variable you define in the loop is each individual `film`, so I replaced `films` with `film`.

Comment: Even though the comment default says avoid saying "thanks", I still wanted to thank you. Life saver

Answer (score 0):

In your view, you only pass one context object to the template, `direct`. This `direct` is a member of your director model: it makes sense that `direct` in your template displays the name of the director, since that is how you define the `__str__` method for that model.

Beyond that, though, none of your other variables will display. Why?

- You use `director.photo` instead of `direct.photo`. `director` is undefined in the template. (As a side note, `director` is IMO a better variable name.)
- You use `direct.rating` and `direct.title` even though these are attributes of the `Film` model. You will need to modify as follows:

```
    <ul>
        {% for film in direct.films_set.all %}
        <li>{{ film.title }} - {{ film.rating }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

(I also changed `films` to `film` since that more accurately reflects the variable's content.)

Comment: For the current view, it should be `direct.films_set.all()`. I would prefer to change the view to use `director` then use `director` everywhere in the template.